# Best Structure for a Markov Chain

Tags: c++, algorithm, c++11, markov-chains

I'm designing a simple Markov Chain in C++ that will take a state of type `T` and and size `N`. I have a few questions pertaining to how the state should be designed and what the best/most efficient container would be to store this. I need to map a state, which contains `N` elements of type `T`, to a single value of type `T` along with a weight.

The markov chain is primarily going to be used for strings, but it should allow for an arbitrary size, and ideally, an arbitrary type.

**The state**

The state should be hashable (or at least allow for easy calculation of the hash). The current option is to use `std::vector<T>` or `std::deque<T>` and and iterative/cumulative hashing algorithm such as Boost's `hash_range`. With strings, though, there is an increased chance of collisions, particularly with larger state sizes (although sane values will be no higher than 5-7 or so). However, I don't see a way around this. Instead of storing each state monolithically, it's

**Container**

I looked into using an adjacency matrix. O(N) complexity required to find all assosciated states, and of course O(1) for indexing, but the issue is that I can't even use `vector<bool>` specializations to save space since I need to store a weighted value, so this will seem to use a huge amount of unnecessary memory. The vast majority of the connections will be 0.

Current idea:

```
using T = /*some type*/ std::string;
using state_t = /*some type that will contain N elements of type T*/;

// the value (unhashed) and weight
using key_t = std::map<T, unsigned>;

// keep track of N-sized states only when they're at the beginning of a sequence
// Key: the hash of the state
// Value: The entire state (unhashed)
std::unordered_map<size_t, state_t> beginning_states; 

// Otherwise, only keep track of the hash of the state to conserve memory
// Key: the hash of the previous state
// Value: the next value of type T and a weight (incremented by 1 each time)
std::unordered_map<size_t, key_t> connections;
```

I would then use a `std::deque<T>` variable and iterate through the user's given input. It will maintain a size of `N` and will `pop_front`/`push_back` as needed. Each `N`-sized state will get its cumulative hash stored and associated with the next value.

My question is, does using this style with standard containers provide too much overhead? Is there a more efficient option that's relatively easy to implement?

***Note:*** it occurs to me that non-integral values of `T` (i.e. string) may result in a lot of duplicates being held in memory. It may be wise to have a template specialization for integral/pointer types that store the key directly, but for other types, store the full unhashed value and an index/counter in another container.

Comment: This question is very broad. I guess nobody can tell you for sure without having tried themselves.

Comment: An alternative for the `std::map<T, unsigned>` could be a `std::vector<std::pair<T, unsigned>>`

Comment: @Jodocus How can I specify? I'm wondering if the STL containers I'm using is the most efficient way to get this done without re-inventing the wheel.

Comment: I think there should be a sorted vector type for when you have less than 4096/(element size) elements. If all your elements fit on a page, a map is likely adding more overhead than the speed advantage you get during inserts or deletes.

Comment: For strings, or other heavy objects, use an index into a Markov-chain-wide vector of strings. A variant of the Flyweight pattern.

Comment: wouldn't it be better to store it in array of N elements and overwrite it circularily?

Comment: @Omnifarious Thank you, that's all good information to research!